# Jquery - Embedding Label's text value into anchor href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want `$("#lblCompany").text()` to be searched on Google. How can I embed it below?
Tried `<a href='https://www.google.com.tr/search?q='" +$("#lblCompany").text()+ "'`. Didn't work. Redirecting to `https://www.google.com.tr/webhp`

```
$(".block1").bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
    $("#plus").append("<a href='https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=' target='_blank'");
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: `$("#plus").append("<a href='https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=ABCCompany' target='_blank'");`This one obviously shows the google results for 'ABCCompany'. I want the search term to be taken from `$("#lblCompany").text()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect to href when click on the link.

```
$('#lblCompany').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + $(this).text());
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Hope helps you!